# An Error Occurred Installing Boot Loader (SLES 10.1)

Tags: grub, boot-loader, sles10

I am trying to install SLES (SuSE Linux Enterprise Server) SP 1 onto a server but I'm having an issue with the bootloader.

I go through the install, more a less default options except Gnome Desktop is not installed and the OS appears to install without issue until the boot loader. When I then get the error `An error occurring during bootloader installation. Do you want to try again?`.

If I say `yes` it then takes me to the Boot Loader option but I can't see any issues so I say finish but I then get the same error as above. If I say no, the rest of the OS installs but when it then does the reboot it fails to load the OS.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

**UPDATE**
When I go into rescue mode and try to install the boot loader I get:

```
 /dev/cciss/c0d0p3 doesn't have any corresponding BIOS drive
```

Comment: What if you try to run install grub from the command line?

Comment: I just get a read only file system so it can't install the grub boot loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the procedure to manually reinstall grub from here:
http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7001376

It seems that the kernel and grub can't map the disks on your raid array.

Comment: Thanks this has been bugging me for weeks, everything I tried failed.